# postgres : column "id" violates not-null constraint\n Detail: Failing row contains

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework

Hi i'm new with java web develpment
i wrote a simple play framework app with java
i want to save some contact in a ebean database it works well in my pc
i deployed my app in heroku and i'm using postgres plugin

the problem is when i POST the following request i get that error
req:/contacts/post?name=name&email=email%40mail.com&phone=234234

err:
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[PersistenceException: ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint\n   Detail: Failing row contains (null, name, 234234, email@mail.com).]]

but if i add &id=223434 it works well!!

Comment: Make the id column a serial so you don't need to pass it.

Comment: thnaks it worked but raised another error -_-